# Set of zeros of a differentiable function $f$ such that there is no $p$ that satisfies $f(p) = f'(p) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, roots

Suppose $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $[0,1]$ and there is no $p \in [0,1]$ such that $f(p) = f'(p) = 0$. The set $$Z = \{x \in [0,1] ~| \ f(x) = 0\}$$
is finite?

I looked for strategies that involved the Mean Value Theorem or Rolle's Theorem, but I didn't even come close to proving such a problem.

Comment: Hint: Suppose infinite zeros, and use compactness and Rolle's theorem to find sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ converging to some $p$ such that $f(x_n) = f(y_n) = 0$ for all $n$. Given $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f'(y_n)}{1} = 0$, what does L'Hopital's rule tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $Z$ as described above is infinite. Then there exists a sequence $(a_{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ with $a_{j} \in [0,1]$ so that $f(a_{j}) = 0$ and $a_{d} \neq a_{c}$ for $c \neq d$. This sequence has a convergent subsequence as $[0,1]$ is compact so that we have

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}a_{n_{k}} = a \in [0,1]$$

for some sequence $(n_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with $n_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now note that by continuity $f(a) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}f(a_{n_{k}}) = 0$.

And by differentiability we have

$$f'(a) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(a_{n_{k}})-f(a)}{a_{n_{k}}-a} = 0.$$

This is a contradiction as we cannot have $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) = 0$.